# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined when iterating through index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

when I try to run this code:

```
var str = 'exercise_files_attributes_' + index + '_content';
var textarea = $('textarea[id=str]');
alert(textarea.val());
```

Basically I try to get content of textarea, but in alert I only get message "undefined".

When I am getting textarea by

```
var textarea = $('textarea[id="exercise_files_attributes_1_content"]')]');
```

everything works fine.

When I print value of index, I get correct response as well.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: `$('textarea[id=str]')` ==> `$('textarea[id="' + str + '"]')`

Comment: Or perhaps `$('#' + str)`

Comment: $('textarea[id=str]'), Here str as string 'str', That's the only reason that you are getting undefined textarea. You should use $('textarea[id="' + str + '"]') then you will get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your selector, see here.

```
var str = 'exercise_files_attributes_' + index + '_content';
var textarea = $('textarea[id=str]'); // <-- str is a string and -----  
alert(textarea.val());                                               -
                                                                     -
$('textarea[id="' + str + '"]'); // < -- should be like this ---------
```

You used `str` as a string thats why JavaScript doesn't find your element.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
var textarea = $('textarea[id="exercise_files_attributes_'+index+'_content"]')]');
```

Comment: var textarea = ('textarea[id="exercise_files_attributes_'+index+'_content"]'); worked fine, thanks!

Comment: then accept my answer. haha....